Which is the correct way to add a web link in a Kotlin app?
I have created a dynamic link to google map and I want to show it on form as clickable. I have defined some fields on the form, like below. But, I suppose the TextField is not the correct way to show a link. How to do it? The link looks correct, but it is just text, not a link.
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

    TextField(
        label = { Text(text = "Content") },
        value = description,
        onValueChange = { description = it },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

    TextField(
        label = {Text(text = "")},
        value = mapLink,
        onValueChange = {  },
    )


You can use a TextButton (or any kind of button). Another option is to use a Text modified to be clickable and styled to look like a hyperlink.

This looks like Compose, not just "a Kotlin app". If it is, please clarify that, as it's a key detail, and add the appropriate tags.
